# JavaScript: Filtering between the same nested key using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array `baseTable`, which looks like this:

```
baseTable = [
    {
        exid: "2",
        name: "aa",
        children_meta: {
        has: false
        }
    },
    {
        exid: "1",
        name: "aa1",
        children_meta: {
        has: false
        }
    },
    {
        exid: "3",
        name: "bb",
        children_meta: {
        has: true
        },
        children: [
        {
            exid: "101",
            name: "c101"
        },
        {
            exid: "102",
            name: "c102"
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

and another array `againstTable` like this:

```
againstTable = [
    {
        exid: "2",
        name: "aa",
        children_meta: {
        has: false
        }
    },
    {
        exid: "3",
        name: "bb",
        children_meta: {
        has: true
        },
        children: [
        {
            exid: "102",
            name: "c102"
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a lodash method to select objects from the `baseTable` array where the same `exid` does not exist in the `againstTable`?

To illustrate, I need method that can produce the following array result from the two arrays above:

```
 [
    {
    exid: "1",
    name: "aa1",
    children_meta: {
        has: false
    }
    },
    {
        exid: "3",
        name: "bb",
        children_meta: {
        has: true
        },
        children: [
            {
                exid: "101",
                name: "c101"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is how I was trying but this method becomes too big for a small task:

```
conditionalRender(o: { baseTable; againstTable }) {
    const { baseTable, againstTable } = o;
    // Check if there are no duplicates in the base
    // table; check against, "against table"
    // This could be possible after user performs a search
    console.log(baseTable, "..base");
    console.log(againstTable, "...againsr");
    const baseMap = {};
    const againstMap = {};
    baseTable.forEach(row => (baseMap[row.pid] = row));
    againstTable.forEach(row => (againstMap[row.pid] = row));

    // const against_ids = new Set(againstTable.map(({ pid }) => pid));
    // return baseTable.filter(({ pid }) => !against_ids.has(pid));
    const filteredBaseTable: { [index: string]: any } = [];
    baseTable.forEach(({ pid }) => {
    if (baseMap[pid].children_meta.has) {
        // If it is a group, check if there exists
        // a part in another table
        if (againstMap[pid]) {
        // Opposite table also has the same eequipment group
        // Will keep the children that are not present in the
        // opposite table
        // Each child can be differentiated by its exid
        const exidsInAgainstTable = new Set(
            againstMap[pid].children.map(crow => crow.exid)
        );
        // Keep only those ids in base table that do not exist in against table
        const originalBaseChildren = baseMap[pid].children;
        baseMap[pid].children = originalBaseChildren.filter(
            ({ exid }) => !exidsInAgainstTable.has(exid)
        );
        filteredBaseTable.push(baseMap[pid]);
        }
    } else {
        if (!againstMap[pid]) {
        filteredBaseTable.push(baseMap[pid]);
        }
    }
    });
    return filteredBaseTable;
}
```

Comment: But `exid: 3` exists in both arrays, so won't that be excluded...unless you keep it *only* if the children's `exid` are different? This isn't the easiest data structure to work with.

Comment: @JackBashford If the same `exid` exists for parent in both the structures, the filter must be applied to the children `exid`. Thus in this case, parent remains on both the structures but the number of children vary.

Comment: Can the children have children?

Comment: @JackBashford Never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved without `lodash` [using build-in array reduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

For instance, you could call `reduce` on the `baseTable` array where for each iteration, you search for an item in `againstTable` that matches on `exid`.

If no match is found, add the `baseItem` to your output array (this represents the case where **exid: "2"** from your data above is added to the result).

If a match is found, examine the children sub arrays of both `baseItem` and `againstItem` (if present), and filter items in the `baseItem.children` array where that child's `exid` never occours in the `againstItem.children` sub-array. If the filtered result is non-empty, update the `baseItem` children array with the filtered result and add that to your `output`.

One way to express this is code would be:

```js
const baseTable=[{exid:"2",name:"aa",children_meta:{has:false}},{exid:"1",name:"aa1",children_meta:{has:false}},{exid:"3",name:"bb",children_meta:{has:true},children:[{exid:"101",name:"c101"},{exid:"102",name:"c102"}]}];const againstTable=[{exid:"2",name:"aa",children_meta:{has:false}},{exid:"3",name:"bb",children_meta:{has:true},children:[{exid:"102",name:"c102"}]}];

const result = baseTable.reduce((output, baseItem) => {

  const matchOnExid = againstTable.find(againstItem => { 
      return againstItem.exid === baseItem.exid; 
  });

  if (matchOnExid) {

    /* If match of exid found from agaistTable for current baseTable item
    then examine the children sub-arrays */
    const baseChildren = baseItem.children;
    const againstChildren = matchOnExid.children;

    if (Array.isArray(baseChildren) && Array.isArray(againstChildren)) {

      /* If valid children sub-arrays exist of items, filter a subset of the
      baseItem children for items that do not exist in the children sub-array
      of the matched againstItem */
      const matchChildrenOnExid = baseChildren.filter(baseChildItem => 
      {
          return againstChildren.every(againstChildItem => {
              return againstChildItem.exid !== baseChildItem.exid;
          });
      });

      if (matchChildrenOnExid.length > 0) {

        /* If a subset of children do exist, then baseItem can be added to
        resulting array. Note also that we need to update the children array
        of the returned result to reflect the subset that was just found */
        output.push({ ...baseItem,
          children: matchChildrenOnExid
        });
      }
    }
  } else {
    /* If no match of exid found, just add the baseItem to the
    result */
    output.push(baseItem);
  }

  return output;

}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It must also output the object from base table having `exid` as `1` since that is not present in the against table.

Comment: Opps sorry missed that - let me update the answer. Just a moment